# Returning value from normal function which called suspend function using Kotlin Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Hi I am using Kotlin coroutine library in a project.

The below method calls a suspend function which return a boolean value.

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context?): Boolean {
            //return checkNetworkReachability(context)
            var isNetworkAvailable = false
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
                isNetworkAvailable = GlobalScope.async<Boolean> {
                    checkNetwork()

                }.await()
            }
            return isNetworkAvailable

        }
```

Here checkNetwork is the suspend function. Before executing it the return value is passed to the caller (View/Activity).
How could I achieve without making the "isNetworkAvailable" as suspend?.

Inside the checkNetwork method, to check reach-ability calling network call as like below.

```
private suspend fun checkNetwork() : Boolean {
            val value = GlobalScope.async<Boolean> {
                val isEastReachable = async { checkEastReachable() }
                if (!isEastReachable.await()) {
                    checkWestReachable()
                } else {
                    true
                }
            }

            return value.await()
        }
```

And the sub-methods are

```
private suspend fun checkEastReachable(): Boolean = coroutineScope {

                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    repository.networkManager.callReachableEast()
                }
            }



private suspend fun checkWestReachable(): Boolean = coroutineScope {

                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    repository.networkManager.callReachableWest()
                }
            }
```

The sub-suspend methods are calling a web service using retrofit. As it would return a boolean, I made it as an synchronous .execute() call.

```
fun callReachableEast(): Boolean {
        return try {
            val requestCall =
                ApiService.create("eastApi").getReachabilityEast()
            requestCall.execute().isSuccessful
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }

    fun callReachableWest(): Boolean {
        return try {
            val requestCall =
                ApiService.create("westApi").getReachabilityWest()
            return requestCall.execute().isSuccessful
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
```

I have gone through the below links

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html

https://proandroiddev.com/async-operations-with-kotlin-coroutines-part-1-c51cc581ad33

and some more.

Repeating my question, How could I achieve without making the "isNetworkAvailable" as suspend?.

Comment: What did you mean by ~ "**Before executing it the return value is passed to the caller**"

Answer (score 10):

If you can't make `isNetworkAvailable` a `suspend` function, then it will be a blocking function. This means, any code calling `isNetworkAvailable` will block as well, or you'd need to change this function's signature to have a callback instead.

First, let's look at the blocking version. There is a special coroutine-builder that is suited for bridging from the suspendable world into the regular/blocking world. It is called `runBlocking`:

```
fun isNetworkAvailable(context: Context?): Boolean = runBlocking {
    checkNetworkReachability(context)
}

...

val isAvailable = isNetworkAvailable(activity)
if (isAvailable) { ... }
...
```

If you'd like to change its signature and have a callback instead of a return-value:

```
fun CoroutineScope.isNetworkAvailable(context: Context?, callback: (Boolean) -> Unit) { 
    launch {
        callback(checkNetworkReachability(context))
    }
}

...
scope.isNetworkAvailable(activity) { isAvailable ->
    if (isAvailable) { ... }
}
```

(code may have typos)

Comment: Yes I achieved with blocking (runBlocking). Will try with callback .

Comment: Should we use `runBlocking` in Android UI layer?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No. Never call runBlocking directly from the main UI thread.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston it be nice to include the alternative and justify why you wouldn't call this in the UI thread, just saying for others who read it later. please include more information on it.

Comment: Plus one to @EvOlaNdLuPiZ from someone who is reading it later and would love more detail. 